# Div overlapping parent div

Tags: html, css, layout, overlapping

I'm trying to achieve the below:

[image]

So the darker blue box will be the parent `div` and then the teal blue one will be the child `div`, see the above image.

I have the below code, but can't seem to work out how to achieve it!

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #6ca591;
}

.container {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 80px;
}

.portfolio_main_img {
  background-color: #327acd;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.portfolio_main_img img {
  margin: -28px auto 0 auto;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="portfolio_main_img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C/O https://placeholder.com/">
  </div>
</div>
```

If anyone could help me out or give me some tips it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing margin collpasing where the negative margin is pulling the container instead of only the image. Change the image to `inline-block` to avoid this and center it using `text-align`

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #6ca591;
}

.container {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 80px;
}

.portfolio_main_img {
  background-color: #327acd;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  text-align:center;
}

.portfolio_main_img img {
  margin: -28px auto 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="portfolio_main_img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C/O https://placeholder.com/">
  </div>
</div>
```